# IIS Redirects to multiple subfolders then errors

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an issue I can't seem to figure out.  When I go to access my url `example.com/subfolder` it redirects to

`example.com/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder`  and keeps going until I get a url max length error.

Any ideas? I can't find anything while searching around.

Comment: What Web server are you using ? IIS ? apache?

Comment: Could you post the config you are using (or the parts that are relevant)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if This is happening in IIS you need to give the status code of permanent and use the redirect to be "absolute" instead of relative.

The HTTP redirect is a feature in the Web server role.

[image: Http Redirect Instalation]

---

Once it's installed (maybe you have it already installed). You need to change the redirection from Relative to Absolute and give it the URL. To do this you need to open IIS, move to your site (the problematic one) as picture showed

[image: http redirect icon and information]

---

And check the configuration, it should be something like:

[image: IIS Redirection]

IF it's not IIS or it's maybe a php code, you need to check in the code the line that is 'in charge' to do the redirections and correct it.