# IIS Redirects to multiple subfolders then errors when I use different rule name

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, rewrite

I have a very strange issue which I couldn't figure out. In the IIS under URL rewrite module I have a redirect rule, which works absolutely fine when it is under a specific rule name, however, when I change rule name it redirects to so many subfolders. For example, when I set my rule name "Redirect to signup page" and access the URL

> example.com/companyName/login

it redirects me to

> example.com/subFolder/companyName/login

which is what I wanted. However, as the rule name doesn't reflect what the redirect rule is doing here, I want to keep the rule name as "Redirect to login page". When I change the rule name it doesn't work and accessing the same url redirects me to

> example.com/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/...(many repetition)..../subfolder/companyName/login

this issue is almost similar to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/843050/iis-redirects-to-multiple-subfolders-then-errors/843060#843060?newreg=bd8b4e5da3e34454b2cd08bbce6c93cf), but, the solution in there doesn't work for me.

the rule in my web.config file is following:

```
<rule name="Rediect to login page" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://*/*/login*" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/subFolder/{C:3}/login" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Can you post your rule from web.config please?

Comment: @bjoster I have added the rule from web.config. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: The rule name is just the display name and has no influence on what the rule technically does. As expected, I can't reproduce the problem here. When you do the change, does it change anything else in the web.config (like `patternSyntax` for example)? that would explain a lot ...